# Bit Masking for C++?

Tags: c++, set, byte, bit

I have a flag which is of type uint8, and I wish to check what the decimal value is. I don't need the value as such but i need to know what it results in so i can work from there.

I have a couple of options, so say we have this

```
0x01 = Hello
0x02 = Goodbye
0x04 = Morning
```

Say the variable we are testing is called How can I also check that mybyte contains "Goodbye" and "Morning"?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `mybyte is equal to "Goodbye" for example`: `mybyte==0x02`? I suppose I don't quite understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: `check that mybyte contains "Goodbye" and "Morning"`: `(mybyte & 0x6) == 0x6`

Comment: Sorry, but can someone explain what the question is?

Comment: I basically was asking how do I check that current bit is set and the rest are 0. So to check a byte is 0x02, we need to check if the byte contains the bits 00000010... That's really what I wanted to know but now I know...

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
enum WordMask
{
    Hello = 0x01,
    Goodbye = 0x02,
    Morning = 0x04
};
```

Now, to check if a value contains the flags `Goodbye` and `Morning` (it will not care whether or not `Hello` is set):

```
if ((value & (Goodbye | Morning)) == (Goodbye | Morning)) {
    // ...
}
```

You can generalize this so that you don't have to repeat the flags twice:

```
template <typename T>
bool are_all_flags_set(T value, T flags)
{
    return (value & flags) == flags;
}
```

Then your condition becomes:

```
if (are_all_flags_set(value, Goodbye | Morning)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: so this is known bit masking right?

Comment: @SuzanAydın I don't know what you mean by *known* bit masking.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of flags should be just other way round, as you're trying to do

```
enum MyOptions {
     Hello = 0x01 ,
     Goodbye = 0x02 ,
     Morning = 0x04 ,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can follow the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

enum Flags : uint8_t
{
    Hello  = 0x1,
    Goodbye = 0x2,
    Morning = 0x4
};

inline bool IsSet( uint8_t value, uint8_t f )
{
    return ( value & f ) == f;  
}

int main() 
{
    uint8_t mybyte = Goodbye | Morning;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsSet( mybyte, Goodbye | Morning ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsSet( mybyte, Hello ) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
true
false
```